# Cookies taking too long to save before page redirect

Tags: typescript, cookies, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have the following login and redirect function in my vue3 with Quasar app, it is supposed to log in, save user details, such as token and user info, and then redirect to the home page once the login is successfully performed.
I also have this second function that check if there is a any cookies that contain user information, if not the user is redirected to the login page.
However every time I log in it redirects me back to the login page or if I am able to reach the home page the api calls all give me 404 because they can't read the "token" cookie. IF I refresh the page everything runs normally.
I assume that is because the cookies are not saved yet so how do I guarantee that I redirect ONLY after the cookies are saved?
Also, if what I am doing is wrong or not advisable what would be the best practice for login in Vue3 projects?

Login Function on login component:

```
onSubmit() {
    api
      .post('/login', {
        password: password.value,
        username: username.value,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        //saves user info on cookies, some require to be stringfied
        Cookies.set(
          'user',
          JSON.stringify({
            username: response.data.username,
            id: response.data.id,
          })
        );
        Cookies.set('roles', JSON.stringify(response.data.roles));
        Cookies.set('token', response.data.token);
        router.push({ path: '/' });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // notifies user that something went wrong
        $q.notify({
          color: 'red-5',
          textColor: 'white',
          icon: 'warning',
          message: 'Oooooooops, something went wrong, bro',
        });
        this.onReset();
      });
  },
```

IF there is no "token" cookie the user is sent back to login when he reaches home:

```
onBeforeMount(() => {
      if (!Cookies.has('token')) {
        router.push({ path: '/login' });
      } 
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you can just put Cookies.set('token', response.data.token); in first ?